# High Low priority queues SGE

Tags: cluster, queue, gridengine

I would like to have two queues in a CPU/GPU cluster, one with high priority and one with low priority. Thus, jobs that are submitted in the high priority queue will be bumped to the top of the list with the waiting jobs. How is that possible in SGE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what I did was altering the priority in a 'brute force' way, by adding a "qalter" command inside the prolog file like.

qalter -p 1000 $JOB_ID

Answer (score 2):

From my reading of SGE's [sge_priority(5)](http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/htmlman/htmlman5/sge_priority.html?pathrev=V62u5_TAG), the easiest way to configure hard priorities for jobs is to use projects to distinguish between high and low priority jobs.

Start by [setting](http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/htmlman/htmlman5/sched_conf.html?pathrev=V62u5_TAG) `weight_priority` and `weight_urgency` to zero, while setting `weight_ticket` to one. Set `weight_tickets_functional` to a big value (e.g. 1000000) to push functional tickets to the most important scheduling factor. This disables all user supplied and time-based priority calculations, basing all scheduling solely on the project's tickets.

Then setup [projects](http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/htmlman/htmlman5/project.html?pathrev=V62u5_TAG) for each priority level. Order projects by setting their `fshare` value. Jobs for a project with a higher fshare value are run before jobs for a project with less fshares.

You might want to use `enforce_project` in the main [sge_conf(5)](http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/htmlman/htmlman5/sge_conf.html?pathrev=V62u5_TAG) to force users to always specify a project when submitting jobs.